# How to detect when a player sits

Tags: lua, roblox

I was wondering if there is an easy way to detect when a player sits in a specific chair, other than detecting if the player touches the seat, which doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Humanoid.Seated](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Humanoid/Seated) signal.

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)

        -- listen for when the player sits down
        character.Humanoid.Seated:Connect(function(active, seatPart)
            -- active (bool) : true when a player is sitting
            -- seatPart (Instance of Seat or VehicleSeat) : the seat that the player has just sat in or left
            print(string.format("Is %s sitting? %s", player.Name, active and "yes" or "no")
            print("the seat in question : ", seatPart)
        end)
    end)
end)
```